# Gather stats - Partitioned Table

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle-12c, statistics

Database: Oracle 12c

I have a process that selects data from Fact Table, summarizes it and pushes it to Summary Table.

Summary table is Range Partitioned (Trade Date) and List Partitioned (File Id).

the process picks up data from Fact table (where file_id=<> for all Trade Dates), summarizes it in a temp table and use Partition Exchange to move data from Temp table to one of the SubPartitions in Summary Table (as the process works on a File Id level).

Summary table is completely refreshed everyday (100% data will be exchanged).

Before the data is exchanged at the subpartition level, statistics are gathered and exchanged along with the data.

After the process is completed, we run dbms_gather_table_stats at partition level (in a for loop - for each partition) with granularity set as "approx_global and partition".

Even though we collect stats at the global level, user_tab_statistics for the summary table has "STALE_STATS" = YES for this table, however, partition & Subpartition stats are available.

when we run a query against the summary table (for a date range of 3 years), the query spins for a long time - spiking the CPU to 90%, but never returns any data.

I checked the explain plan on the query, Cardinality is showing as 1.

I read about incremental stats, but it seems increment will work if a few partitions change - it may not be the best option in my case, where data across all the partitions change completely.

I m looking for a strategy to gather statistics on the summary table - don't want to run a full gather stats.

Comment: If you provide explain plan of the slow running query or SQL trace information it would easier to find where the problem is.

Comment: You said "I m looking for a strategy to gather statistics on the summary table - don't want to run a full gather stats." .... try exporting those stats and copying them back on summary table, after the data-load. If your data stays "similar" on day-to-day basis you might be in luck. You may need to adjust some of the high/low values but it isn't impossible.

Comment: @JSaptoka: I checked the explain plan and cardinality estimates were wrong - as I mentioned cardinality came back as 1, even though the table has about 100+ Million records. When the query spans across multiple partitions, it is looking for Global Stats at the table level and that's where the problem is. STALE_STATS for object_type Table is YES.

Comment: @Raj: I read about that option, but somehow not convinced that it will work. But I'll give it shot and see what happens.

Comment: Since the table is completely refreshed every day, it sounds like this may be a good use case for simply locking the table stats and/or locking the partition stats after you have representative data in the table: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68628, https://sqlmaria.com/2017/01/24/locking-table-statistics-provides-plan-stability-true-or-false/, and https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/maintaining_statistics_on_large_partitioned_tables

Comment: @KrisJohnston: Thanks for the pointer. I'm going to try this option now. will keep the group posted.

Comment: Quick update on the progress so far : As I mentioned in my original post, stats are already available at the sub-partition level. I ran gather table stats and set the granularity as PARTITION and that resolved all the partition stats (the job ran for about 20 minutes) and then I tried running gather table stats and set the granularity as GLOBAL and that resolved the table level Stats. At this point I don't see any STALE_STATS in USER_TAB_STATISTICS. I tried the Insert Query and it ran in 33 seconds (wow !!!). I'll post further updates on my analysis.

Comment: we tried locking the table stats and run partition exchange, but it didn't work as expected. Table level stats became stale again. However the following worked for us.                                                                          1. Run the process for full Summarization
2. Compute sub-partition level stats, include it as part of Partition Exchange
3.Run Gather table stats at Partition Level (Granularity set as PARTITION)
4.After Partition Stats are completed.  Gather table stats (Granularity set as GLOBAL).

Comment: @sk411 I'm not sure what you mean by "didn't work as expected".  If you simply mean that STALE_STATS = 'YES', that doesn't necessarily mean the stats are bad or unusable.  That simply means that enough of the table has changed since the last time stats were gathered for that table that Oracle flagged the stats as out of date.  Since you are locking the stats, then rebuilding the table, that will certainly be true... but as long as the stats are representative of the data (num_rows, data skew, etc...) during your workload periods, that is all you need since Oracle will still use those stats.

Comment: @Kris. we completely rebuild the table on a daily basis (per oracle documentation if more than 10% of data is changed, table level stats will be come stale). I thought locking the table stats would not let the stats go stale, but that is not the case.

Comment: @sk411 Did you fully read my comment?  Stale_stats <> unusable stats. Stale_stats are still used by the optimizer. Of course stats will be stale if you lock them, then rebuild the table. That is expected behavior, but that isn't necessarily a bad thing. As long as the stats are still representative of your data after your load and during normal processing when the queries are running that would depend on those stats, then you've achieved your desired goal.

Comment: @Kris. I understand what you are saying. Num_rows reflect close to actual record count in the table. when we run queries against the table with stale_stats=yes, queries keep spinning without producing results. CPU goes up to 99%. But after running gather_table_stats with granularity  GLOBAL (fixing stale_stats), queries are fine.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of a question asked on Stack Overflow :)